# ffmpeg - HDR to SDR - Unable to find a suitable output format for 'format=gbrpf32le'

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc, hdr

I'm on windows 10 using ffmpeg 4.0.2. I found the script for HDR to SDR [here][1], but when I run the script from the bottom of the page:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,
zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,
format=yuv420p -c:v libx265 -crf 18 -preset slower output.mkv
```

I get this error:

```
[NULL @ 0000014588707480] Unable to find a suitable output format for 
'format=gbrpf32le'
format=gbrpf32le: Invalid argument
```

When I run the first script from the page:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -vf select=gte(n\,360) -vframes 1 output.png
```

I get this error:

```
At line:1 char:41
+ ffmpeg.exe -i Hook.mkv -vf select=gte(n\,360) -vframes 1 output.png
+                                         ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
[1]: https://stevens.li/guides/video/converting-hdr-to-sdr-with-ffmpeg/
```

I'm pretty new to ffmpeg, could someone please explain what is going on?

Many thanks!

Comment: Put the vf argument in double quotes i.e. `"zscale=...format=yuv420p"`

Comment: Yep, that did it @Gyan , thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Read this post on how to convert HDR10+ videos to SDR (standard dynamic range), so they can be viewed on non-HDR devices with brightful and not washed-out colors as the original:

https://www.maxvergelli.com/how-to-convert-hdr10-videos-to-sdr-for-non-hdr-devices/

this is the batch command:

```
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i video-input.mp4 -vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,format=yuv420p -c:v libx265 -crf 22 -preset medium -tune fastdecode -t 90 video-output.mp4
```

Comment: Been using this for a while. Sometimes the video comes out too dark. In that case, reducing the npl=100 to npl=50 or thereabouts helped a lot. Just try different values until the result looks good.